# How many same time login possible for one user account ( domain)

Tags: user-accounts, active-directory

I am using Active directory 2016 and want to use same user login in multiple locations same time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit by default. An active login does not permanently occupy any AD resources, and there isn't even any central tracking of "login sessions" – the domain controller only issues a Kerberos login ticket and forgets about it. (New tickets do not invalidate old ones, either.)

(If you're using *Roaming Profiles* then I believe the limit is sort-of 1, because a user's "central" profile on the fileserver can only be in use by one computer at a time, and logins on additional computers will use a temporary profile without any of the user's settings. However, roaming profiles are *not* active by default, and Microsoft generally recommends not using them at all.)